# How to parse xml file from appcelerator

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, appcelerator-studio

I'm building an app with appcelerator.
Now I want to parse a local xml file. So I'm putting this file in asset/XML folder/CCD.XML.
Now I'm build this code to parse it:

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,'/XML/CCD.xml'); 
if ( file.exists() ) {
    var xmltext = file.read().text;
    var doc = Ti.XML.parseString(xmltext); 
    var nodes = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("templateId");

    for (var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
        var element = nodes.item(i);

    }
}
```

This is the xml file:

```
<typeId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" extension="POCD_HD000040"/>
<templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1"/> <!-- CCD v1.0 Templates Root -->
<section>
    <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.13'/> <!-- Purpose section template -->
    <title>Summary Purpose</title>
    <entry typeCode="DRIV">
        <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.30'/> <!-- Purpose activity template -->
    </entry>
</section>
<section>
    <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.15'/> <!-- Purpose section template -->
    <title>Summary Purpose</title>
    <entry typeCode="DRIV2">
        <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.35'/> <!-- Purpose activity template -->
    </entry>
</section>
```

Now I want to get all Nodes that the root value of "templateID" tag is "2.10.xxxxx".

Comment: 2.10.x is never going to match anything in your xml as everything starts with 2.16

Comment: @Kevin Kloet, mu number of 2.10.xxx is only an example. I know if in this small xml is not exists 2.10.

Comment: you could try this: `if(nodes[i].getAttribute('root').indexOf("2.10.") !== -1){/*code you want to execute if root contains 2.10.*/}` inside your for loop.

Comment: thanks, but I want to know if is possible to find that element never cycle for. For example with this code, " var nodes = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("templateId");" I can get all nodes that have tag name = templateID

Comment: i don't think there is a way to do this without looping as far as i know.